# Material-UI V5 RTL with stylis-plugin-rtl

Tags: material-ui, next.js

i am useing Material UI 5 with next.js and have implemenmted every steps exactly like the documentation here with emotion and stylis-plugin-rtl v2:
https://next.material-ui.com/guides/right-to-left/#heading-jss
but after refreshing page my label in input jumping to left and by clicking goes right and in outlined mode label placement in border is ltr
can anyone help?

```
import rtlPlugin from 'stylis-plugin-rtl';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';

// Create rtl cache
const cacheRtl = createCache({
  key: 'muirtl',
  stylisPlugins: [rtlPlugin],
});

function RTL(props) {
  return <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>{props.children}</CacheProvider>;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should detect when your app is in RTL mode, then handle the `createCache` options like this:

```
const cacheRtl = createCache({
  key: isRTL ? 'muirtl' : 'muiltr',
  stylisPlugins: isRTL ? [rtlPlugin] : [],
});
```

Comment: thanks that problem fixed after material ui update. i was using beta version